# Creating a Range Slider (Dates) for a Choropleth Map

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, slider

I've made a map to display the confirmed COVID cases for each state in the United States. However, the dataset I used is filtered so that each state only has one date, 10/22/2020. However the original dataset I want to use, each state has multiple dates. For example, California has data from 1/10/2020 - 10/22/2020, that is why I need the slider so that I can scroll through time and see changes in each state. However, I have no idea at all how to do that. My code so far is this:

```
document.getElementById("slider").value = 0;

    var width = 1400
    var height = 600

    const niceFormat = d3.utcFormat("%B %d, %Y");
    const dataFormat = d3.utcFormat("%m/%d/%Y"); // MM/DD/YY
    const dataParse = d3.utcParse("%m/%d/%Y");

    const startDate = dataParse("01/21/2020");
    const millisecondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    const valRange = [1000, 10000, 100000, 150000, 200000, 250000, 300000, 350000, 400000, 450000, 500000, 550000, 600000];
    const rateType = "Confirmed";


    const slider = d3.select("#slider").on("input", function () {
        var date = new Date(+startDate + millisecondsPerDay * this.value);
        update(date);
    });



    const colormap = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain(valRange)
        .range(["coral", "violet", "indigo", "green", "blue", "#eeeeee", "yellow", "orange"]);

    const svg = d3.select("#mapsvg_pr");
    const tool_tip = d3.tip().attr("class", "d3-tip").offset([-8, 0]);
    let allStats;

    Promise.all([
        d3.json(
            "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mheydt/29eec003a4c0af362d7a/raw/d27d143bd75626647108fc514d8697e0814bf74b/us-states.json"
        ),
        d3.csv("states_only.csv")
    ]).then(ready);

// The callback which renders the page after the data has been loaded.
    function ready(data) {

        const us = data[0];

        allStats = data[1].map(function (row, i) {
            return {
                Updated: dataParse(row.Updated),
                Updated: dataParse(row.Updated),
                AdminRegion1: row.AdminRegion1,
                Confirmed: row.Confirmed,
                ConfirmedChange: row.ConfirmedChange,
                Deaths: row.Deaths,
                DeathsChange: row.DeathsChange,
            };
        });

        // Find the maximum date with data
        const availableDays =
            (d3.max(allStats, function (d) {
                    return d.Updated;
                }) -
                startDate
            ) /
            millisecondsPerDay;
        slider.attr("max", Math.round(availableDays));
        slider.attr("class", "slider");

        render(us);
        update(startDate);
    }

// Helper function which, given the entire stats data structure, extracts the requested rate for the requested state
    function getStateMetrics(stats, state_name) {
        for (var i = 0; i < stats.length; i++) {
            if (stats[i].AdminRegion1 == state_name) {
                return stats[i];
            }
        }
    }

// Renders the map once, don't fill it in yet
    function render(us) {
        const projection = d3
            .geoAlbersUsa()
            .translate([width / 2, height / 2]) // translate to center of screen
            .scale([1280]); // scale things down so see entire US

        // Define path generator
        const path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

        svg.call(tool_tip);

        svg
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "states")
            .attr("class", "state-borders")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(
                us.features.filter(function (d) {
                    return d.properties.name !== "Puerto Rico";
                })
            )
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .on("mouseover", tool_tip.show)
            .on("mouseout", tool_tip.hide)
            .attr("d", path);
    }

    var zoom = d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1, 2])
        .on('zoom', function() {
            svg.selectAll('path')
                .attr('transform', d3.event.transform);
        });


    svg.call(zoom)
    svg.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.scale(1));


// Update the map with the data for the selected date
    function update(date) {
        const stats = allStats.filter(function (row, i) {
            return +row.Updated === +date;
        });

        d3.select("#date").text(niceFormat(date));

        tool_tip.html(function (d, i) {
            const stateMetrics = getStateMetrics(stats, d.properties.name);
            let html =
                "<table>" +
                "<tr><th>Name:</th><td>" +
                stateMetrics.AdminRegion1 +
                "</td></tr>" +

                "<tr><th>Confirmed Cases:</th><td>" +
                stateMetrics.Confirmed +
                "</td></tr>" +

                "<tr><th>Changes in Confirmed Cases:</th><td>" +
                stateMetrics.ConfirmedChange +
                "</td></tr>" +

                "<tr><th>Deaths:</th><td>" +
                stateMetrics.Deaths +
                "</td></tr>" +

                "<tr><th>Changes in Deaths :</th><td>" +
                stateMetrics.DeathsChange +
                "</td></tr>" +
                "</table>";
            return html;
        });

        svg.selectAll("path").attr("fill", function (d) {
            const metrics = getStateMetrics(stats, d.properties.name);
            if (metrics === undefined) return "#ddd"; // missing data
            const rate = getStateMetrics(stats, d.properties.name)[rateType];
            return colormap(rate);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set `min` and `max` of the slider using `d3`, and if you treat it as "day 0" through day 365, you don't need to know or even deal with dates in your application. I assume every file in your system has a date in their name somehow, so then I would continuously load the data like this:

```js
var startDate = new Date("2020-01-01");
var millisecondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

var availableDays = Math.ceil((Date.now() - startDate) / millisecondsPerDay);

d3.select("#slider")
  .attr("max", availableDays)
  .on("input", function() {
    update(+this.value);
  });

var niceFormat = d3.timeFormat("%B %d, %Y");
var fileFormat = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d");
d3.select("#date").text(niceFormat(startDate));

function update(selection) {
  var currentDate = new Date(+startDate + (millisecondsPerDay * selection));
  d3.select("#date").text(niceFormat(currentDate));

  console.log("Loading file", fileFormat(currentDate));
  d3.csv("covid_cases_per_day-" + fileFormat(currentDate) + ".csv").then(function(data) {
    ready(data);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <input id="slider" type="range" min="0" step="1" value="0">
  <span id="date"></span>
</div>
```

---

**Edit**: from your comment now understand that you have one file with multiple values. That changes the code to something like the following, based on your previous question.

- I load in the entire file and store it as a global variable;
- I also store the `valRange` and `rateType` globally, because they never change. Things that do change, like the current date, I don't store globally;
- I split the drawing into a function that first creates the map and a function that colours it in. The first part is only called once, the second part is called every time the slider changes.

```js
const states = [
  "Arizona",
  "California",
  "Nevada",
  "New Mexico"
];
const niceFormat = d3.timeFormat("%B %d, %Y");
const dataFormat = d3.timeFormat("%m/%d/%y"); // MM/DD/YY
const dataParse = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%y");

const startDate = dataParse("01/01/20");
const millisecondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const availableDays = 5;
const valRange = [200, 400, 800];
const rateType = "Confirmed";

const csvData = "AdminRegion1,Updated,Confirmed\n" + states.map(function(s, i) {
  let cases = 100;
  return d3.range(availableDays).map(function(d) {
    // Calculate the correct date
    const date = new Date(+startDate + (millisecondsPerDay * d));

    // Increase the number of cases randomly
    cases *= Math.random() + 1;

    return [s, dataFormat(date), Math.ceil(cases)].join(",");
  }).join("\n");
}).join("\n");
console.log(csvData);

d3.select("#slider")
  .attr("max", availableDays)
  .on("input", function() {
    var date = new Date(+startDate + (millisecondsPerDay * this.value));
    update(date);
  });

const colormap = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(valRange)
  .range(["blue", "#eeeeee", "red"]);
const svg = d3.select("#mapsvg_pr");
const tool_tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-8, 0]);
let allStats;

Promise.all([
  d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mheydt/29eec003a4c0af362d7a/raw/d27d143bd75626647108fc514d8697e0814bf74b/us-states.json"),
  Promise.resolve(d3.csvParse(csvData))
]).then(ready);

// The callback which renders the page after the data has been loaded.
function ready(data) {
  // Render the poverty rate map.
  const us = data[0];

  allStats = data[1].map(function(row) {
    return {
      Updated: dataParse(row.Updated),
      AdminRegion1: row.AdminRegion1,
      Confirmed: row.Confirmed
    };
  });
  render(us);
  update(startDate);
}

// Helper function which, given the entire stats data structure, extracts the requested rate for the requested state
function getStateMetrics(stats, state_name) {
  for (var i = 0; i < stats.length; i++) {
    if (stats[i].AdminRegion1 == state_name) {
      return stats[i];
    }
  }
}

// Renders the map once, don't fill it in yet
function render(us) {
  const projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa()
    .translate([500 / 2, 300 / 2]) // translate to center of screen
    .scale([500]); // scale things down so see entire US

  // Define path generator
  const path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

  svg.call(tool_tip);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "states")
    .selectAll("path")
    // NOTE: The filter here is only to make the example simpler
    .data(us.features.filter(d => states.includes(d.properties.name)))
    .enter().append("path")
    .on("mouseover", tool_tip.show)
    .on('mouseout', tool_tip.hide)
    .attr("d", path);
}

// Update the map with the data for the selected date
function update(date) {
  const stats = allStats.filter(function(row) {
    return +row.Updated === +date;
  });

  d3.select("#date").text(niceFormat(date));

  tool_tip
    .html(function(d, i) {
      const stateMetrics = getStateMetrics(stats, d.properties.name);
      let html = "<table>" +
        "<tr><th>Date:</th><td>" + dataFormat(date) + "</td></tr>" +
        "<tr><th>Confirmed Cases:</th><td>" + stateMetrics.Confirmed + "</td></tr>" +
        "</table>";
      return html;
    });

  svg.selectAll("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      const rate = getStateMetrics(stats, d.properties.name)[rateType];
      return colormap(rate);
    });
}
```

```css
.d3-tip {
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.6;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-tip@0.9.1/dist/index.js"></script>
<svg id="mapsvg_pr" width="800" height="400"></svg>
<div id="container">
  <input id="slider" type="range" min="0" step="1" value="0">
  <span id="date"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: so where the d3.csv line is towards the end, that is where I enter my csv file name.

Comment: Yes exactly. I now assumed a `YYYY-MM-DD` format, but it could be anything else. Look at [the docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format) for more info

Comment: I can change it in excel using the format cells option

Comment: But what I was confused about is how to connect it to the map you helped me make?

Comment: You call the function `ready()` from that example, with the newly loaded data. So you take the new data, and recalculate the `fill` for all paths based on that new `stats` object

Comment: Because if you look at the dataset picture, the Updated Column it is formated M/DD/YY so I should change it right?

Comment: This is about the filename. You said earlier that you had one file per day, right? Or do you put it all in the same CSV file?

Comment: No, no, I think I explained that completely wrong. I apologize. So basically the I had one file, the one above, which contains a bunch of dates for each state. However, I used python to created another csv file so that each state only has one date, 10/22/2020. However, I am trying to use the file above, which has all the dates for each state. Does that help sir?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223782/discussion-between-ruben-helsloot-and-beginner-coder1).